# Why does Twilio REST API v2 keep giving me a 400 Bad Request error?

Tags: javascript, rest, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio

I keep receiving 400 Bad Request errors from Twilio REST API. My only requirement is that I have to use the `fetch` because I will be running this code in a Zapier code block.

I've rewritten the following code a bajillion different ways and cannot seem to make the request work. I feel like I might just be missing something very obvious. Please help, Stack Overflow! You're my only hope.

```
const func = async () => {
  var url = "https://studio.twilio.com/v2/Flows/{Flow ID}/Executions";
  var phone = "+1" + "{phone num}";
  phone = phone.replace(/-/g,'');
  console.log('running');

  output = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      To: phone,
      From: '+1{phone num}',
      // Parameters: JSON.stringify({
      //   item_num: "A11113232",
      //   agent: "Joel"
      //   // driver_num: '1',
      // }),
    }),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic '+Buffer.from('{SID:Secret}').toString('base64'),
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
      },
    }).catch((err)=>console.log(err));

  console.log(output.status);
//} 
}

func();
```

Comment: Twilios API client for NodeJS defines the `Content-Type`-header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Otherwise I suspect there might be something related to the values you pass in to string substitutions, namely `Flow ID` or `phone num`.

You can use `console.log(err.body)` to see what the error might be related to.

Comment: @Nict I was able to make the call work from Postman using `form-data`

Comment: This is all the body tells me `ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }`. I'm confident the problem is not with `Flow ID` or `phone num`

Comment: BUT @Nict , that was the problem. Had to use URLSearchParams not JSON. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it's not very clear why they have two versions of the api both using `v2` but it appears you may be using the wrong body parameters. the 400 response means you sent some bad data in the request body.

Try using
`to:` and `from:` (lowercase)

source: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution#create-a-new-execution

Comment: You are reading the documentation for the Twilio Node.js client. Their API do indeed expect upper case key names.

Comment: From the source code: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/src/rest/studio/v2/flow/execution.ts#L602

Comment: the node sdk uses To: and From:. the rest api, which the OP asked about is using lowercase per the link I provided.

Comment: I tried both ways and am still getting the same error

Comment: @JeremyFiel No, it's the other way around. The REST API endpoints require To and From, while Node SDK changes lowercase "to" and "from" to upper case first letter. Check the documentation for how to do the request with cURL in their examples

Comment: @nict  what? the LOC above your last link shows they are expecting lowercase `to` and `from`.  https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/src/rest/studio/v2/flow/execution.ts#L592

Comment: Yes, the parameter when using the node.js-api. When consuming the REST API directly they translate the object keys to ucfirst. OP is not using the Node.JS API client, they are consuming the API directly.

Comment: i know that, that's the reason I suggested using the lowercase variants.   you're the one who suggested they were using the node sdk. my link to the docs is the rest api.